# JsonConvert.SerializeObject: Unexpected result when Serializing null value

Tags: c#, json, null, json.net, null-string

In the line of code below, my `string x` ends up being an actual string "null" when `clInitializer.AVOptions = null` value:

```
string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clInitializer.AVOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

As in actual word "null" and not a `null` value or perhaps `{}`. I am not sure this is expected behavior.  Does anyone know how to make it not return the word "null", or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding on how `JsonConvert` works.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `NullValueHandling` has to do with null values for a property and not the object it self.

For example, if you have the below example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string NullProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then you serialize it:

```
var obj = new ExampleClass();
var jsons = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Then the `NullProperty` is ignored and you get `{}`.

**Edited**

The reason why "null" is returned is because the RFC for JSON (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) explicitly states the following:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
> false null true
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are
> allowed.
>
> value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
>
> false = %x66.61.6c.73.65   ; false
>
> null  = %x6e.75.6c.6c      ; null
>
> true  = %x74.72.75.65      ; true

**Edited:**

I originally had a work around, but I removed it because I really think you should follow the RFC.  The RFC clearly stated that a NULL object MUST be represented by a "null" so any work around is not a good idea.

To stay with the RFC, I would store "null" or return "null" and not NULL. When you deserialize "null" it will return a NULL value.

Answer (score 4):

A value of null will always return the null string.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(null, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

Will return the string `null`.

If you were to pass in the object `clInitializer` that has a null `AVOptions` then with your `JsonSerializerSettings` it would Ignore the property `AVOptions` and not have that in the string.   If your `clInitializer` object only had the property `AVOptions` (or only null properties) then you would get `{}` returned when passing in `clInitializer`.

Answer (score 0):

{} would be an empty json object though (not null). So the only thing it can return is "null" which is the json representation of a null object. I think if you want an actual null string you'd need to just put an if statement around the call like so:

```
    string x = null; 

    if (clInitializer.AVOptions != null) {
        x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clInitializer.AVOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
    }
```

UPDATE: Please see @Rogala's answer for why you should consider not disregaring the returned "null" value.

Comment: The is not a good answer because it goes against the RFC.  I'm not sure how it was marked as the correct answer.